# Patent Expiration

Tags: patent-lifetime, expiration, us5858064

In reference to the patent: [US 5,858,064](https://www.google.com/patents/US5858064)

I think this patent has expired based on the priority date of August 22, 1995. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. This patent expired on August 22, 2015. The earliest document in the claims of domestic benefit is Serial Number 518,020, with a filing date of August 22, 1995:

> Continuation of Ser. No. 822,141, Mar. 17, 1997, Pat. No. 5,766,308, which is a continuation of Ser. No. 518,020, Aug. 22, 1995, Pat. No. 5,611,845.